# How to capture extra css class in addition to the pseduo class in this less (css) code?

Tags: css, less

It is my existing `less` code:

```
  .my-form {
    .form-control {
      &:focus {
        border-color: blue;
      }
  }
```

It will set the border color of `.form-control` to blue whenever it gets the focus.

Now in addition to the focus event, I want to set the border color to blue when the '.my-form' element has an additional class 'active'.

I can repeat myself, but it is not ideal:

```
  .my-form {
    .form-control {
      &:focus {
        border-color: blue;
      }
  }

  .my-form.active {
    .form-control {
        border-color: blue;
      }
   }
```

But this does not work obviously:

```
  .my-form {
    .form-control {
      &:focus,
      & .active {
        border-color: blue;
      }
  }
```

I think I can define a function to set the border color. But is there any way I can express this more concisely? Hopefully it can be next to the `&:focus` selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is this:

```
.my-form {
   .form-control {
      &:focus, .active& {
        border-color: blue;
      }
   }
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/stufu/pen/yLNbpej)

`.active &` would output

`.active .my-form .form-control`

`.active&` would output

`.my-form.active .form-control`